# How to pass variable into HTML class tag in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Working in WordPress PHP I am trying to pass a value into class tag of an element

```
<div class="element-item"></div>
```

to be like

```
<div class="element-item comedy"></div>
```

Code:

```
$term = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'type' );
echo '<div class="element-item '.$term.'">';
```

the value is popping out of the class tag and display on the page:

[image]

I checked the source code and it seems that I am passing entire a link to the class tag:

```
<div class="element-item " .<a="" href="http://www.domain.ca/type/meat/" rel="tag" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">Canadian</div>
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you read `get_the_term_list` description?

Comment: I know this returns  a link but how can I only get the slug? not link?

Comment: Use another function?

Comment: Bro! this is exactly my question! What function?!

Comment: No, this is not your question. Your question is why something outputs not the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, may be it will help you

```
$html_output = '<div class="element-item ' . $term . '">';
echo $html_output;
```

Comment: Thanks Nahid but the value still is in link format and publishing out of the div!

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
 echo "<div class="element-item $term>";
```

or
you can do it with help of javascript like this one

```
 $(function(){
   $('.element-item').addClass('<?php echo $term ?>');
   });
```

let me know if you face any issue

Answer (score 0):

You've correctly identified the problem in terms of the return value.

The issue is here:

```
$term = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'type' );
```

`get_the_term_list()` will return a HTML string as described in the documentation for the function: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list

I'd suggest the following approach:

```
// We're going to place all of our classes into this array.
$classes = array( 'element-item' );

// Get terms assigned to post.
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'type' );

// Check terms were found.
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {

    // Loop through each found term and add it to the array of classes.
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $classes[] = $term->slug;
    }
}

// Convert the array of classes into a string separated by spaces.
// Escape the value before outputting inside the attribute tag.
printf( '<div class="%s">', esc_attr( implode( ' ', $classes ) ) );
```

Further reading: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms